# Fixing street names with regex

Tags: php, regex

I've got to solve a regex problem that might be to specific, looking through Stack overflow I've made some good discoveries, but have not been able to piece them together to make it work.

Basically I want this:

`lorem ipsum north road` => `lorem ipsum rd (n)`

`north lorem ipsum rd` => `lorem ipsum rd (n)`

`lorem ipsum road north` => `lorem ipsum rd (n)`

As part of an auto complete program i need to convert partial text to the correct version so it can check the database

`lorem ipsum so`***uth rd*** => `lorem ipsum rd (s)`

`west lorem ipsum roa`***d*** => `lorem ipsum rd (w)`

I don't want somebody to code this program for me, but I would like to know the best way of tackling the problem.

Now you might ask me why I bother, as people would not write with such f'd up grammar, but that's because I'm not only dealing with English :(

Cheers

Comment: This is a massive challenge. I have previously created a RegExp which found street types (ie "Street","Lane","Avenue","Ave",etc.) but even that was a RegExp of over 200 characters. To solve this would be more complex than that. Edge cases like "North Rd", "West Ave", etc. would make it even more challenging.

Comment: I think that this is the sort of question that should not be solved with a single big regex. It would be simpler to break the task up into small steps and do those separately: e.g. check for north, n...etc and add an "(n)" to the end; check for the other directions; check for abbreviations of "road"...etc. If you do each in a different step, it will probably be easier to follow and easier to write.

Comment: Ooh, another thought: if you do it step by step, you'll have the option to undo your modification and try the lookup again: it's possible that some street has something in the actual name which you replaced.

Comment: it's a complex problem, and double-replacements can cause issues. I'd scan strings against all your known auto-corrections, keep a list of changes to be made for the string, and apply them only after determining if strings match a standard pattern - to avoid doubly replacing anything.

Answer (score 3):

Seems to me that the most difficult bit is to look for the proper words in the proper location in the line with regexps, so, although not elegant, could this be a more managable way to do it with minimum regexp? :

1. Extract all the known words and
   their variations (road types,
   direction, numbers, ...) from the
   address line and, hopefuly, we would be left with
   the road name.
2. Compose the address line back, but in
   the order we need (road name + road type + direction).

Once you get rid of the position, the posible theoretical variations are still large but the predictable variations shouldn't be that large ?, even accounting for spelling mistakes: Avenue: Avenu, Avene, Aveniu, Avn, Av, Avn. Road: Rd, Roud, Roade, Roud?

Comment: This is how I would do it as well. A regex would be too format dependent to be able to perform the job properly, as the user can type in *anything*, in *any* order. By removing all known words (and combinations) and keeping track of all those changes, you may be able to get proper results.

Comment: I've done this before in VB6 for an app that created mailing labels every day. It was a successful approach, but you definitely need to do the legwork on all the combinations you want to replace. Every now and again, I'd run into problems with crazy addresses, so you'll need to keep an eye on things and add negative filters (strings to not touch) for the occasional crazy addresses that aren't in a regular pattern.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question, would the following pseudo regex look something like what you are after?

```
(<direction>?) <road name> (<direction>?) <road type> (<direction>?)
```

Then you check for each of the three optional `<direction>` regex, including whatever condition you want to give it. You will need to come up with the `<direction>`, `<road name>`, and `<road type>` regex yourself. Those regex should probably be specific, e.g. (road)|(rd)|(street)|(st).

For the 2nd part of the question (i.e. auto-complete), you may need to index some or all of the regex categories mentioned above (i.e. directions, road names, and road types), depending how much you want to auto-complete.